# WCF Service client in Portable Library referenced from desktop app not firing Completed event

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, desktop-application, portable-class-library

I have a NetHttpBinding WCF Service referenced in a portable class library. In my WCF service, I have a ValidateLogin(username, password) method.

The portable class library calls ValidateLoginAsync(username, password) and subscribes to the ValidateLoginCompleted event.

All of this works great when the portable class library is being referenced from a Windows 8.1 app. However, when I reference the portable class library from a desktop app, the ValidateLoginCompleted event is never fired. I verified that the server is receiving and returning the request and that the the following auto-generated method is being fired on the client:

```
public DataAccessClientWrapper.DataAccessService.ValidateLoginResponse EndValidateLogin(System.IAsyncResult result)
{
     object[] _args = new object[0];
     DataAccessClientWrapper.DataAccessService.ValidateLoginResponse _result = ((DataAccessClientWrapper.DataAccessService.ValidateLoginResponse)(base.EndInvoke("ValidateLogin", _args, result)));
     return _result;
}
```

I am aware that NetHttpBinding client-side code looks different in portable class libraries than it does in normal desktop apps. In a portable class library, it creates a ValidateLoginAsync(username, password) method and a ValidateLoginCompleted event. In a desktop app, it creates an async ValidateLoginAsync(username, password) method and a ValidateLogin(username, password) method. However, I would still expect a desktop app to work when referencing a portable class library.

Any help?